# How to structure unit tests when you want to test interactions of derived classes wih base class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I started organizing my unit tests in the way Phil Haack suggested [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx). My test classes have one nested class per public method under test. The nested classes are derived from the outer class in order to inherit its setup code.

I now have a case where I want to test a simple hierarchy of one abstract base class and two derived classes. I would like to test the interactions of each derived class with base class explicitly rather than testing the base class with some kind of mock derived class.

I've done this in the past using a base test fixture and one derived fixture per derived class where the derived fixtures have to implement a few template methods for the tests in the base fixture:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseFixture
{
    protected abstract MyBaseClassUnderTest GetTestInstance();

    [Test]
    public void SomeMethod_SomeCondition_SomeOutcome()
    {
        var sut = GetTestInstance();

        //test base class behavior here
    }

    //More base class tests here
}

public class DerivedFixture : BaseFixture
{
    protected override MyBaseClassUnderTest GetTestInstance()
    { 
        return new DerivedInstance(); 
    }

    //Tests for derived class go here
}
```

Does anybody have an idea, how I can resolve this? Right now I can't see, how I can combine the two approaches, because of the different inheritance strategies (inheriting setup code from the outer class versus inheriting base class tests from base class fixture).

Answer (score 2):

It's a really interesting problem, of course multiple inheritance isn't possible therefore I guess you need to find an alternative to one of the two inheritance strategies you are using.

Personal opinion is that you should keep the *Haack* method of organizing tests for consistency across the test suite, and look for an alternative to your approach for sharing tests through a class hierarchy. The closest concept I know to multiple inheritance is that of `Mixins`, and if you look at this answer to [Is it Possible to Implement Mixins in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255556/1980029) it appears that mixins can be simulated using extension methods. I would go down this path - [this blog post](http://colinmackay.co.uk/2008/02/24/mixins-in-c-30/) discusses possible strategies for creating mixins that can access data held in the class that uses them, which you would require I believe to be able to supply the derived class instance to your base class level tests (i.e. replacing `GetTestInstance`).

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but could you think of an actual example for an NUnit test fixture, which the test runner would actually be able to run? I can't.